# Curl - does not list the contents of wonder to me

Tags: php

Could someone look at the script below, why do not list the contents of wonder ( < div > < / div > ) , even if the address is correct .

```
    <?php
function get_content($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    ob_start();

    curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    $string = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();
    $divs = '/<div>(.+)<\/div>/U';
preg_match($divs, $string, $matches);
$vysledek = $matches[1];
    var_dump($vysledek);
    var_dump($url);
}
echo get_content ("http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/garthbrooks/midnightsun.html");
?>
```

var_dump me writes :
NULL
string ( 59 ) " http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/garthbrooks/midnightsun.html "

Earlier I used :

```
function ziskatlyrics($url)
{
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $first_step = explode( '<div>' , $content );
    $second_step = explode("</div>" , $first_step[1] );

    $obsah = strip_tags($second_step[0]);
    return $obsah;

}
echo ziskatlyrics("http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/garthbrooks/midnightsun.html");
```

But it throws me this error:
Warning : file_get_contents (
http://www.azlyrics.com/...ightsun.html
) : Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed ! in

I can do something to make it functional again ?
Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're just `var_dump()`'ing variables, not the response from the curl request...

```
var_dump($vysledek);
var_dump($url);
```

What you want is to assign the curl response to a varaible and return that...

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
return $response;
```

Well...after you've done the regex you're doing in there, as I assume your `$string` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I'm so correctly:

```
function get_content($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

    ob_start();

    curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    $string = curl_exec ($ch);

    ob_end_clean();
    $divs = '/<div>(.+)<\/div>/U';
preg_match($divs, $string, $matches);
$vysledek = $matches[1];
return $vysledek;

}
echo get_content ('http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/garthbrooks/midnightsun.html');
```

And the result: [link](http://michales.eu/web.php)